# Symfony2 Custom Form Type or Extension

Tags: forms, symfony, autocomplete

An Entity Order exists with a property Product.

A form has been created OrderType that allows a Product to be added to an Order.

This works, however it's not very interesting.

Instead of showing a simple Product drop down, it should be an autocomplete.

However when choosing an autocomplete value some additonal fields should be populated with information about the product.

Choosing a product from the autocomplete should populate two additional fields with Price and Code.

The controller method to return the data has aleady been created and jquery have some handy autocomplete functions avaiable.

I know how to hack the solution directly into the form template but I would like to make a reusable component.

The question is how do I create a custom form or extension with this behaviour?

```
class Order {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="orders", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;  

    protected $quantity;
}

class Product {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="product")
     */
    protected $orders;

    protected $name;
    protected $price;
    protected $code;
}

class OrderType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('quantity')
            ->add('product');    
    }
}
```

**Update**
I have updated OrderType with the following:

```
    $builder
        ->add('ppprice', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'data' => 2));

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use($builder) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $order = $event->getData();
        $builder
            ->add('ppprice', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'data' => 21));
        $builder
            ->add('test', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'data' => 21));
    }
    );
```

PRE_SET_DATA is being called but the new form field test is never added and ppprice is not updated with the new value.

How do I get PRE_SET_DATA to update the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach a `FormEvent` that handles the `POST_SUBMIT` event on your forms. 
There's a tutorial with a full example (incl. jquery ajax behavior) here: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

This will take care of adding dynamic fields to your `FormType`. You can create an `EventListener` if you are looking to re-use this later, or you can attach the event via `Closures` when building your custom form type.

***Update:***

Try the following code first to see and check if the PRE_SET_DATA event properly kicks in. Please note that you can not inject `$builder` into this `Closure`. (You can but won't work) Simply use the `$form` object and `->add` fields in the `Closure` like this:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $order = $event->getData();

        $form->add('ppprice', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'data' => 21));
        $form->add('test', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'data' => 21));
    }
    );
```

Comment: So for price and code I would add $builder->add('price', array('mapped' => false)); to OrderType but how exactly would I use FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA to populate price and code with values if they're editing a Order?

Comment: Adding `mapped` `false` depends on your underlying entity. If you don't wish to persist that into the database, then it should be `false`. Regarding the dynamic population of price and code during editing you need use the `POST_SUBMIT` event in your form. The cookbook link has an example just like that. Here's the anchor: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Comment: I've looked at the Sport POST_SUBMIT example but not seeing how to use it in my example, I have updated the question with the new code.

Comment: Thank you that works, is that the best way to do it?

Comment: It's the advised way to do it, since it is reusable this way. And this would prevent extra form fields 'appearing' in your form (prohibited by `Symfony` `Form` Component.)

Comment: I've done a follow up question if you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084301/symfony2-custom-field-type-from-populate-with-values