# Symfony2 Custom Field Type from Populate with values

Tags: php, forms, symfony

This is a follow on from the earlier question [Symfony2 Custom Form Type or Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079288/symfony2-custom-form-type-or-extension)

I am trying to attach a custom field type for Product on an Order.  The name field will contain the product name and the id field the product id.

I am using FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA to try and populate the data but it throws an error, getData() returns Form\Type\ProductAutoCompleteType.

How do I correct the code?

OrderType has the following:

```
    $builder->add('product', new Type\ProductAutoCompleteType(), array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Product'
    ));
```

ProductAutoCompleteType:

```
class ProductAutoCompleteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('name');
        $builder
            ->add('id');

    /* Turns out this is not needed any more
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $product = $form->getData();
        $form
            ->add('name', 'text', array('mapped' => false, 'data' => $product->getName()));
    }
    );  
    *//

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'productAutoComplete';
    }
}
```

**Updated**

Error: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getProduct() on a non-object in /var/www/symblog/src/Acme/TestBundle/Form/Type/ProductAutoCompleteType.php line 26

**Controller**

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $order = $em->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Order')->find(6);

    $form = $this->createForm(new OrderType(), $order);
```

**Updated 2**

After changing the field [product][id] and submitting the form I now get the following error, I assume this is because the field name is [product][id] and not [product]?

Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "setId()", "**set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Proxies__CG**\Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Product".

**Updated 3**

I have it submitting data to the controller now, in my controller on submit I have had to add the following, it looks messy to do validation and attach the product this way, is this the right way?

```
        $data = $request->request->get($form->getName());
        if ($data['product']['id']) {
            $product = $em->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Product')->find($data['product']['id']);
            if ($product) {
                if ($product->getShop()->getId() != $order->getShop()->getId()) {
                    $form->get('product')->get('name')->addError(new FormError('Invalid shop product'));
                }
                $form->getData()->setProduct($product);
            } else {
                $form->get('product')->get('name')->addError(new FormError('A product must be selected'));
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the error thrown?

Comment: Added error to question in updated.

Comment: When you create your form in your controller. Are you passing an `Order` `Entity`?

Comment: Yes, I've added the code to the question as well.

Comment: Since this event is `PRE_SET_DATA`, I think you don't have the $order in there just yet. Try using the `POST_SET_DATA` event for this case. (I do hope I am not pushing you into a completely wrong direction when getting you implement a form listener. Could be that I don't see your complete use case.)

Comment: I'm just trying to get the hang of Symfony forms and find out the capabilities of them. Switch to POST still means getData() returns ProductAutoCompleteType What I am tyring to do is create a ProductField which I can reuse and has autoCompletes.

Comment: Try `$order = $form->getData();` for now. And set `data_class` attribute in your `setDefaultOptions()` http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-data-class

Comment: I've updated the question with code changes, the form is now populated however saving fails. I also used $product = $form->getData(); instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55222/discussion-between-debreczeni-andras-and-lookbadgers).

Comment: Sorry I missed you in chat the other day, I've have got it working, I'm just not sure about the code I have added to hte controller it feels wrong to do validation and set form values like that. (Updated 3)

Answer (score 0):

Putting all your logic into the controller is not a good practice. Your forms should handle as much of this as possible to ensure reusability of these forms.

If the Order that you query does not have a related product in it, then it's normal that `$form->getData()` returns null.

**Debugging tip:**

Output the value of `$form->getData()` to inspect the Product object.
Output the value of `$form->getParent()->getData()` to inspect the Order object from the parent form.

**Validation tip:**

In case a product in this form can be null, make sure that you only set the name field's data if the product is not null.

**Query tip:**

Since the `findBy` method on the repository will not automatically include the related `product`, I recommend using a QueryBuilder and make a join. Example in the controller:

```
$order = $em->getRepository('AcmeTestBundle:Order')
  ->createQueryBuilder('order')
  ->select('order, product')
  ->innerJoin('order.product', 'product')
  ->where('order.id = :order_id')
  ->setParameter('order_id', $order_id)
  ->getQuery()
  ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Of course, having so much code in your controller is not great either, so once you get your stuff working, create a custom repository with a custom method and move this code there.

In your entity:

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\TestBundle\Repository\OrderRepository")
 */
class Order {
```

In your repository

```
class OrderRepository {
  public function findByIdWithProduct() {
    // $order = $this->createQueryBuilder...
    return $order;
  }
}
```